# How do Import multipage PDF file Automatically?

Tags: vector, creative-cloud

I am using InDesign CC program and it takes longer time to place page by page, so I am wondering if there is a better way to import all the pages once I have done all my settings?

Answer (score 0):

I use the Multipage Importer Script. It was last developed for CS5 but still works with CC. Here is a write up on how to use it and downloads http://indesignsecrets.com/zanelli-releases-multipageimporter-for-importing-both-pdf-and-indd-files.php